# Write DVD video directly to an ISO (rather than disk) using Windows 7 DVD movie software

Tags: windows-7, video, iso-image, burning, dvd-burning

I am helping some volunteers create videos for funeral homes, and one of the DVD video software tools (FuneralOne) that they use requires a DVD to be burned each time.

In many events, we don’t want a DVD burned *then*, but rather want to get an ISO to someone else in a different part of the country so that they can then burn the image to a disk.

Is there a driver that I can load on the Windows machine that will emulate a DVD disk and “trick” the DVD program to simply burn an image rather than waste a DVD?

Once it's an ISO, then the people at the other end can easily open with VLC to check out the video, and if it’s cool, *then* burn it. Rather than having to burn a DVD each time this is done.

Comment: Could use a rewriteable DVD-RW, at least it wouldn't "waste" a dvd-r disk

Comment: If you have the files and simply want to make an ISO, you can use a program like *ImgBurn* to create an ISO from files. You could then upload the ISO to some cloud storage for someone to download. You could also use a daemon like *DaemonTools* to mount a virtual drive and it should be able to play the file, without burning it to a disk. Hopefully I understood your question correctly and this answers your question.

Comment: Xen2050, unfortunately I cannot.  That was the first thing I tried!

Comment: Dr Zoo, unfortunately it doesn't work like that.  The DVD video program from FuneralOne only is a project file (with pictures).  When you run it, it simply takes those pictures, adds music, and then automatically spits out a DVD (non RW).  I'm trying to "trick" the program into simply outputting an ISO so I don't burn a DVD until I am ready to.